# How can I export my friends' contact information from GMail, Yahoo, and Facebook using PHP?

Tags: php, contacts

How can I export my friends' contact information (name, email, etc.) from GMail, Yahoo, and Facebook using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about API access through each of these applications before you can even begin to grab the data. I suggest you Google on acquiring contacts for each of them. I'll help you get started though with a few links: https://developers.google.com/ http://developers.facebook.com/ http://developer.yahoo.com/. If you read up on each of those you should be more than capable of acquiring the information you seek. Just remember that if you plan to get a person who is not you give up this information they need to approve the connection to you through each API.